# HTTParty parsing JSON in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, httparty

I have a URL that displays JSON holding info for 400 YMCA locations. My goal is to be able to pull latitude and longitude for each location in order to display the points on a map.

I was playing around with HTTParty and just wanted to start by displaying only the latitude and longitude in the view.

Here is my controller:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'httparty'
class HomesController < ApplicationController
  include HTTParty

  def index
    uri = HTTParty.get"http://www.livestrong.org/we-can-help/ymca.json"
    @place = JSON.parse(uri.body)
  end
end
```

Here is the view:

```
<% @place.each do | key, value | %> <br>
  <strong><%= key %></strong>
  <%= value %>
<% end %>
```

So far this displays all of the JSON on the screen. How do I pick out the individual parts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to take hints from what is displayed, if you take a look then I'm sure you'll see that your loop is only executed once, and the one and only key output is `ymca` with all your data in that single `value` of that key.

If you drop into `irb` and take a look at what's in `@place['ymca']` then you'll see it's a big array. If you take a look at the first element of that array then you'll see it's very manageable chunk of data:

```
[12] pry(main)> @place['ymca'].first
=> {"phone_number"=>"205-870-0144",
 "title"=>"Mountain Brook YMCA",
 "street_address"=>"2401 20th Place South",
 "email"=>"livestrong@ymcabham.org",
 "city"=>"Birmingham",
 "lat"=>33.487881,
 "zipcode"=>"35223",
 "description"=>"Mountain Brook YMCA",
 "state"=>"Alabama",
 "thumbnail"=>"v1414706252/tak5bi22hve474jeh1yr.png",
 "website"=>"http://ymcabham.org",
 "lon"=>-86.78624}
[13] pry(main)>
```

I hope you can take it from there.

Comment: Now that you have some points, there's an even better way to thank people here on Stack Overflow :)